# R: Run Function over multiple object in dataset

Tags: r

I have data point that represent behavior of my machines. I would like to detect the change point.

First: My R script run successfully, to find change point over the data that include one machine (the object) as.

```
  library("changepoint")
  Onecpt = cpt.mean(df$prob)
  summary(Onecpt)
```

Now my data consist multiple machines, how to run the function over these machines, then I can do summary for each machine separately, and here is what I expect the script to be look like, but of course it will not work:

```
df <- read_excel("C:..../changepoint/Data.xlsx" , "SHEET")
cpt_function <- function(dataset) {
#you implement this using whatever method you want
model <- cpt.mean(df$success,method="PELT",penalty="Manual",pen.value="2*log(n)")
return(model)
} 
results <- by(df, df$machine_id, cpt_function)
```

My main goal is to do summary function for each one after I run the main cpt.mean function such as following:

```
summary(results$`16915976`)
```

However, I got change points for all machines in the data, not only machine_id = 16915976.

Comment: What does this line do? `model <-= cpt.mean(df$prob)`

Comment: @NelsonGon,  `df$prob` is the data which we wish to find a
changepoint. `cpt.mean` is the function to find the changepoint

Comment: What is `<-=` supposed to do?

Comment: @NelsonGon  Its only the expected code. It is not working and i need some hint and help

Answer (score 0):

I was using `df` instead of the function argument `dataset`. So it should be

`model <- cpt.mean(dataset$prob,method="PELT",penalty="Manual",pen.value="2*log(n)")`